# Scikit Learn Find most representative words by TFIDF, in subset of entire corpus

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I would like to do two things.

1. Find the most representative words in a corpus based on TFIDF
   measures.
2. Find the most representative words for a subset of the
   same corpus.

I have a corpus of approx 10,000 pieces of text held in one column in a Pandas dataframe and I've created a tfidf matrix using this entire corpus.

```
corpus = df['clean_text']

tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1,3), min_df = 0, stop_words = 'english')
tfid_matrix = tf.fit_transform(corpus)
```

I can also query my Pandas Dataframe `df` to provide me a list of document indexes that contain the query term.

```
def get_subset_index(df,query):
    query_list = df[df['clean_text'].str.contains(query,case=False)].index.tolist()
    return list(query_list)

query_list = get_subset_index(df,'myquery')
```

I then use this list in the following code which uses each index number to find the corresponding section in the tfidf matrix and then print a set of representative keywords. The code was adapted from another Stack submission [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782367/how-to-find-out-which-words-are-most-representative-based-on-their-tfidf-index-a).

```
top_n = 10
query_list = get_subset_index(df,'algorithm')
for i in query_list:
    wordindexes =  tfid_matrix.getrow(i).todense().A1.argsort()[-top_n:][::-1]
    print (wordindexes)
    wordfeatures = tf.get_feature_names()
    for i in wordindexes:
        print (wordfeatures[i])
    print ("-----------------------next doc")
```

This provides me with keywords representative of each individual document, but I want a list of keywords representative of the sub-corpus overall. I presume an answer to this question 2 would also help me with question 1.